# How to create dynamic IDs from a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of tabs in a foreach loop. Is there a way I can dynamically add ID's? So that when I click on each of the tabs it loads up a new panel.

**Tab Menu**

```
<ul class="nav tabs-left tabs-border fullblock">
@foreach (var registrationtarget in Model.Tenants.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" title="@registrationtarget.Name"><p class="registrationtarget">@registrationtarget.Name<br />@registrationtarget.TenantGroupName</p>@registrationtarget.CAEIPINumber</a>
    </li>
}
```

**Main View**

```
<article class="row">
    <h1 class="pageTitle artistHeader fw200 mb20 mt10">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="row rowflex;">

            <div class="col-md-2 padzero">

                <div class="panel panel-visible" id="tabContainer">

                    @Html.Partial("_VerifiedSongsTabMenu", Model)

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 padzero">
                <div class="panel panel-visible" id="tableContainer">

                    @Html.Partial("_VerifiedSongsList", Model)

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**Table with ID**

```
<div class="tab-block mb25">
@*Panel Body*@
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab14_1" class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="panel-body pn">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable admin-form theme-primary verifiedsongsTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
                <thead id="tableHeader">
```

I know that its possible to do it using JQuery, but as I have a list of tabs I am unsure of what the best approach would be to get the tabs changing the content when clicked.

Comment: You are asking for an approach so just ask clearly what you are looking for. The code is too long, a low chance to get an answer. Jquery data table is nice you can use it. http://prabodhsatyal.com/DB/OilList check this once.

Comment: @UjwalNeupane I am looking for a way to switch between the list of tabs I have in a `for` loop. I dont think the code is too long, I would rather put what I have so far. Plus I cant simply use JQuery as the id for each table is different. So could I do it based on the Name?

Comment: So you want to add list items depending on the Name or you want to add a list item for every Name? or neither? haha

Comment: @GeorgeB it's confusing. So I have a tab menu that is generated as a list of tabs using a foreach loop. But I want it so that I can change the tabs. But I am not sure if its possible?

Comment: By 'change' what do you mean? Change which one's are visible or what information they hold?

Comment: @GeorgeB I mean when you click on a tab it should change what information is shown. As I know JQuery you can do it with `ID` so that it matches the ids to verify what is shown.

Comment: @Rob You could use the razor ActionLink, then put the tabs in a layout file and call views from there?

Comment: @GeorgeB the tabs are currently in its own partial.

Comment: @GeorgeB tried that and that doesn't seem to work. I am thinking that maybe it's not possible to do, due to having the tabs loads as a list.

Comment: @Rob have you tried breaking on the method the action link calls and making sure that it is getting hit?

Comment: @GeorgeB yes I have tried that. It is getting hit but the tabs are not changing.

Comment: @Rob but are the views changing? if so you could use Jquery events to change the tab focus on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using ActionLinks:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "Tab"})
```

Then in the controller you can return the new view:

```
public virtual ActionResult ActionName()
    {
        return View(); //this will return ActionNameView.cshtml
    }
```